# Issues with shorewall

Tags: firewall, squid

I'm new to using Ubuntu OS and its interface and using terminal.

Recently I was trying to deploy `squid`, and `shorewall` firewall. Even though shorewall is running I can't get through one command, i.e. `shorewall show connections`

```
root@hassaan-OptiPlex-GX620:/usr/share/shorewall# shorewall show connections
Shorewall 4.5.5.3 Connections (5 out of 63584) at hassaan-OptiPlex-GX620 - Thu Aug 29 14:33:36 PKT 2013

grep: /proc/net/nf_conntrack: No such file or directory"
```

I get this message.

Please help me with this problem.

By the way I am using [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-shorewall-firewall-configuration/).

Answer (score 1):

just install the package conntrack 
`sudo apt-get install conntrack` , or by your favorite way to install packages.